# In Python bytecode, why is there a POP_TOP instruction after the CALL_FUNCTION instruction if the function returns nothing?

Tags: python, return-value, bytecode

I'm studying Python bytecode, and I find that there is a `POP_TOP` instruction after the `CALL_FUNCTION` instruction. What does the `POP_TOP` do here?

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b
print(c)
def func(e, f, g):
    h = e + f + g

func(a, b, c)
```

After run `python3 -m dis main.py`, I got

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (c)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             18 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 POP_TOP

  5          24 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object func at 0x7fb9aebb59c0, file "btins3.py", line 5>)
             26 LOAD_CONST               3 ('func')
             28 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             30 STORE_NAME               4 (func)

  8          32 LOAD_NAME                4 (func)
             34 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             36 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             38 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             40 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             42 POP_TOP
             44 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             46 RETURN_VALUE
```

Please see *line 22* and *line 42*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a function which "returns nothing" in Python. Even when a function doesn't explicitly `return` a value, the function *implicitly* returns `None` (if you `dis.dis(func)` you'll see it in the generated bytecode).

If it didn't do this, the byte code compiler would need to be more complex, because it would need some way to differentiate between functions with and without return values (and since functions are first class objects and can be reassigned, you can't even do this with compile time rules; it would have to be handled on a call-by-call basis at runtime); as is, it can unconditionally treat them as having return values, it's just that some return values (implicit `None`) are less useful than others.

Comment: Adding on to this, one can't even determine if a function returns a value or not. A function can return a value in some cases, and return `None` in others.